# SSH password script using root

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, scripting, redhat

Hello I am trying to work on a SSH password script.

The user I am using is root because this is for a cluster of servers and the root user has password less entry to all of the other servers in the cluster.

What I have here works as on one server

```
echo "Welcome3 | passwd user1 --stdin"
```

This is the script i'm trying to user on the cluster.

```
export HOSTS="server1.server.com
server2.server.com
server3.server.com
server4.server.com
server5.server.com"

for i in $HOSTS
do
echo $i
ssh $i echo Welcome3 | passwd user1 --stdin
done
```

I get the message

"servername
changing password for user user1
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully"

But when I go to login to the other servers with the new password it dose not seem to take.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to login with Welcome3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You changed the password of user1 on your local machine.

Try this:

```
ssh $i 'echo Welcome3 | passwd user1 --stdin'
```